# Meaning of "any thing to like to yield"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “The Crown!” *[Emma said]*
>
> “Yes; if you and Mr. Woodhouse see no objection, and I trust you
> cannot, my father hopes his friends will be so kind as to visit him
> there. Better accommodations, he can promise them, and not a less
> grateful welcome than at Randalls.  is his own idea. Mrs. Weston
> sees no objection to it, provided you are satisfied. This is what we all
> feel. Oh! you were perfectly right! Ten couple, in either of the
> Randalls rooms, would have been insufferable!—Dreadful!—I felt
> how right you were the whole time, but was too anxious for securing
> **any thing to like to yield**. Is not it a good exchange?—You consent—I
> hope you consent?

Emma by Jane Austen chapter 11 volume 2

Context: here Frank Churchill is trying to convince Mr. Woodhouse and his daughter Emma to come to the dance party, which the night before was agreed upon to take place in Randalls ( Frank's father's estate), but know it will be in the The Crown inn.

I'm really confused about the bold part, I vaguely understand that "he was too anxious to think of place to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She did not want to yield, until now.

> but was too anxious / for securing any thing / to like to yield

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/like#h447780) has

> **like²**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **2.2 not like doing/to do something**
> Feel reluctant to do something.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't obvious in my post, but Frank Churchill is the one who is saying this paragraph.

Comment: It isn't clear in the better rendering [here](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/emma-227.html) either, where the names Emma and Mr Churchill are not mentioned. Somehow "Emma said" was added to this post, but is not in the link. But the meaning stays the same.

Comment: This is my mistake. I added Emma said to indicate that she said " The Crown!". And then Frank responded by explaining how the idea of changing the place of the party came to be

Comment: Apart from who said it, do you understand my answer?

Comment: I think yes. He's saying that he didn't want to yield because he was too anxious for securing any thing